# SQL query logic, adding rows' fields together

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a web app and need to total a field an array of records.

To further explain please look at the included image:

[image]

This image depicts my output from using the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM logbook WHERE dayNight = 'D'
```

Now what I need to do is total all the values in the `hours` field of all these records.

Once this is done, the output should be something of the following (just as an example):

```
6:05:21
```

Representing HH:MM:SS.

But I would like to represent it in just hours and mins, in a decimal value... So if I had 6 hours and 40 mins and 2 seconds, it would say jsut 6:40. This would be the following structure HH:MM.

So I don't know how to do any of this - but thank you for all the help!

Comment: The `dayNight` field contains the letter D. How is adding the letter D going to result in a time? You must mean some other column. Please clarify that and tag your question with what RDBMS we're supposed to help you with.

Comment: Now that we know you want to add the values in the `hours` column, please share what data type this column is. It looks like a string, while strings aren't easily added. You still need to tag the question with what RDBMS you're using. The answer will depend on that.

Comment: I have fixed this for you - you are right I did mean to say: the `hours` field. And I am using mySQL with php.

Comment: The data type for hours is varChar, yeah string

Comment: That's bad. Can you change it to something that makes more sense? If not, you will have to explain how to parse it. What does "01.00.09 hours" mean?

Comment: I have waited 5 minutes for explanation, now I'll be moving on. I'll leave you with the simple tip that `SELECT SUM(hours) FROM logbook WHERE dayNight = 'D'` would be the query had hours been a number.

Answer (score 3):

You can most of the way with a whole bunch of nasty casting:

```
select cast(sum(cast(hours as time)) as time)
from logbook
where dayNight = 'D'
```

That will give you a result as a `time` value. Then mix in a [`time_format`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format) to get the desired precision:

```
select time_format(cast(sum(cast(hours as time)) as time), '%H:%i')
from logbook
where dayNight = 'D'
```

You should change your `hours` column from `varchar` to [`time`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time.html).

You can get away with just this:

```
select time_format(sum(cast(hours as time)), '%H:%i')
from logbook
where dayNight = 'D'
```

If you want to avoid the extra casting; however, leaving the outer casting in might make things easier to debug later as just `sum(cast(hours as time)` produces things like `234211` for 23:42:11.

---

Once your columns have been converted to sensible `time` columns, then you can do away with all the casting:

```
select time_format(sum(hours), '%H:%i')
from logbook
where dayNight = 'D'
```

or to sum the all regardless of `dayNight`:

```
select time_format(sum(hours), '%H:%i')
from logbook
```

Comment: So thanks heaps for this, I am getting bad responses though: http://benjaminpotter.org/elog/iframe/index.php

Comment: I have converted all the `hours` field to a time data type! So how should I go about this now? Also how would I get the total time no matter the dayNight value? - Again thanks heaps @mu is too short for the help!

Comment: @Ben: See my update please. I had a typo in one of the queries from last night too, that's been fixed.

Comment: That does look better, although I am getting this error:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from logbook LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: "select time_format(sum(hours), '%H:%i') from times from logbook where dayNight = 'D' "

Comment: @Ben: That "from times" stuff was left over copy'n'paste from the table I was testing things with, fixed.